# Zip image gallery for download

Tags: php, download, jpeg

Hi I want to show an image gallery on my site and then have a link that allows the user to download the whole image gallery. Is it ok to place the images in a zipped folder and provide a link to that folder? I had the feeling that it was not a good idea to zip jpegs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of bundling files, it is perfectly acceptable, but it won't reduce the download size by a significant amount.

Comment: Thats ok i just need to be able to provide a link to a folder that won't open but instead download so i think that zipping the folder is the best option. Thanks